# Why does Dune expose only `Foo__.Bar` module, and not `Foo.Bar`?

Tags: ocaml

Here, `utop` are launched via `dune utop`.

#### The problem

Suppose I have initialized a project by `dune init project foo`, and created two files: `lib/foo.ml` and `lib/bar.ml`.

`lib/foo.ml`:

```ml
let x = 3
```

`lib/bar.ml`:

```ml
let x = 4
```

I can access the `x` in `foo.ml` by `Foo.x`.

```
utop # Foo.x;;
- : int = 3
```

But accessing the `x` in `bar.ml` is counterintuitive.

```
utop # Foo.Bar.x;;
Error: Unbound module Foo.Bar
utop # Bar.x;;
Error: Unbound module Bar
utop # Foo__Bar.x;;
- : int = 4
utop # Foo__.Bar.x;;
- : int = 4
```

I thought I could access it via `Foo.Bar.x`, or in general, I could access contents in files in `lib` via `Foo.<Filename with the first letter capitalized>.something`.

For example, [`Re`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/tree/master) provides the [`Pcre`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/blob/master/lib/pcre.ml) module which is stored in [`lib/`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/tree/master/lib), and I can access its contents via `Re.Pcre.foobar`.

```
utop # #require "re";;
utop # Re.Pcre.exec;;
- : rex:Re.re -> ?pos:int -> string -> Re.substrings = <fun>
```

This problem also arises when I write tests. In `test/foo.ml`, I need to write `Foo__.Bar.x` instead of `Foo.Bar.x`.

```
(test
 (name foo)
 (libraries foo))
```

```ml
assert (Foo__.Bar.x == 3)
```

```
%dune test
File "test/dune", line 2, characters 7-10:
2 |  (name foo)
           ^^^
Fatal error: exception Assert_failure("test/foo.ml", 1, 0)
```

If I replace `Foo__.Bar.x` with `Foo.Bar.x`:

```ml
assert (Foo.Bar.x == 3)
```

I can't run tests.

```
%dune test
File "test/foo.ml", line 1, characters 8-17:
1 | assert (Foo.Bar.x == 3)
            ^^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound module Foo.Bar
```

On the other hand, `Re`'s tests [can access the library by `Re.FooBar`.](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/blob/ddbc60f8e37e85f6b53b55fad1853cc97db93912/lib_test/test_str.ml#L40).

#### Question

Why can't I access modules by `Foo.Bar`? The current behavior does not restrict accessing anything in `lib/bar.ml`, but I prefer `Foo.Bar` to `Foo__.Bar` because I feel the former is much more natural.

---

#### Appendix 1. `-for-pack`

After googling for a while, I found [a similar question](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/properly-wrap-a-package-s-modules-with-dune/4404), and [rgrinberg's answer](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/properly-wrap-a-package-s-modules-with-dune/4404/3) said that:

> Your system is basically replicating -for-pack but using a preprocessor.

I tried using the flag:

```
(library
 (name foo)
 (flags -for-pack))
```

but nothing changed.

#### Appendix 2. `(wrapped false)`

[Dune's manual](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html) says that adding `(wrapped false)` exposes modules in the top-level.

```
(library
 (name foo)
 (wrapped false))
```

```
utop # Bar.x;;
- : int = 4
```

However as documented, this pollutes the namespace and thus should be avoided.

#### Appendix 3. Versions

Ocaml: 4.14.1

Dune: 3.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dune does not really expose the name `Foo__Bar` those are supposed to be private module names.

What happens here is that inside a library named `foo`, by convention the compilation unit `foo` is considered to be the entry point of the library that should describe the interface of the library.

In other words, by defining

```ml
(* foo.ml in library Foo *)
let x = 2
```

you are explicitly requesting to dune that module `Bar` should not be exported by the library `foo`.

The solution is thus to either:

- avoid naming a module `Foo` by accident in the library `Foo`.
- or fully define all exported module in the entry point module `Foo`:

```ml
(** foo.ml in library Foo *)
let x = 2
module Bar = Bar
```

Comment: Basically if you don't have `foo.ml` in your library "Foo" then you can think of dune as creating one for you that just exports all the other .ml files it files as sub-modules. If you provide one then it can't do that. It confused the hell out of me first time I stumbled on it too.